# Fetching iTunes RSS feed with Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, rss, itunes

I am willing to fetch iTunes public RSS feed from a appengine java app.

In dev server, here is what I try:

```
URL url = new URL("http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topsongs/limit=10/xml");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
```

And that is the response:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<feed xmlns:im="http://itunes.apple.com/rss" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xml:lang="en"> 
<id>http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topsongs/limit=10/xml</id>
<title>iTunes Store: Top Songs</title>
<updated>2010-11-09T12:45:58-07:00</updated>
<link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewTop?id=38&amp;popId=1"/>
<link rel="self" href="http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topsongs/limit=10/xml"/>
<icon>http://phobos.apple.com/favicon.ico</icon>
<author><name>iTunes Store</name><uri>http://www.apple.com/itunes/</uri></author>
<rights>Copyright 2008 Apple Inc.</rights>`

There is a link, "http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topsongs/limit=10/xml", which is displayed. It is the same URL that the one I give to the java URL object...

If I open this link in the browser, I get the correct XML response.

I tried to set a different user-agent, but nothing changes.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What HTTP response code do you get? Is the server sending a redirect?

Comment: It's ok now, I found my mistake: before writting the response to the page, I was writting some debug info. After that, the XML content was seen as HTML content, and since the XML contains some html redirect code...  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake.

Before outputting the XML response, I were writting some "debug" html data. Thus, the XML was seen like HTML code, but since the XML contained HTML redirections attributes, I was redirected!

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you try "View source" in your browser, you will see the same as you see with your Java snippet.

Comment: Unfortunately, no... I am trying with Chrome, and both "html view" and "source view" show me the XML. I tried with different URL, always provided by Apple's RSS feed generator.